# Can 'cond' fully replace 'if' statements?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I know 'cond' is based off 'if', but can 'cond' do everything 'if' can do?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Any conditional

```lisp
(if x y z)
```

using `if` can be transformed into an equivalent conditional using `cond`:

```lisp
(cond (x y)
      (t z))
```

For example, consider the following:

```lisp
(if (= 1 2) (format t "crazy~%") (format t "sane~%"))
```

The above code can be transformed into:

```lisp
(cond ((= 1 2) (format t "crazy~%"))
      (t (format t "sane~%")))
```

Answer (score 5):

"if" may well be implemented as a macro around "cond". "cond" is the actual "primitive" here, not "if".

Comment: Not according to the CLHS, where `cond` is listed as a macro, and `if` is listed as a special operator. This is in line with Scheme also, where `cond` is a macro atop `if`.

Comment: Chris: true in CL (which this question was tagged as), but not necessarily all dialects.  In McCarthy's original, COND was one of the 7 primitives -- http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html -- though of course it doesn't really matter which is primitive and which is a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which lisp you're dealing with, `if` and `cond` are definitely **not always** interchangeable. Here's a test to find out. The results I give are from MIT's (2014) Scheme interpreter.

## Test

We may design a `new-if` method made using `cond`:

```
(define (new-if predicate then-clause else-clause)
   (cond (predicate then-clause)
         (else  else-clause)))
```

We may try the following with the old-if and the new-if:

```
(define (recursive-func a b)
    (if (= a 0) b
        (recursive-func a b)))
```

`(recursive-func 0 1)`

`=> 1`

And with `new-if`:

```
(define (recursive-func a b)
    (new-if (= a 0) b
         (recursive-func a b)))
```

`(recursive-func 0 1)`

`=> ;Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: The problem with `new-if` is not because of a difference between `if` and `cond`, but simply because the evaluation is not lazy (so both `then-clause` and `else-clause` will always be evaluated). You'd have to define your `new-if` as a macro rather than a function.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks @jkiiski.